# Adding two images PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, image-manipulation

I need this:
[image]

I'm doing this:

```
$top_file = 'image1.png';
$bottom_file = 'image2.png';

$top = imagecreatefrompng($top_file);
$bottom = imagecreatefrompng($bottom_file);

// get current width/height
list($top_width, $top_height) = getimagesize($top_file);
list($bottom_width, $bottom_height) = getimagesize($bottom_file);

// compute new width/height
$new_width = ($top_width > $bottom_width) ? $top_width : $bottom_width;
$new_height = $top_height + $bottom_height;

// create new image and merge
$new = imagecreate($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopy($new, $top, 0, 0, 0, 0, $top_width, $top_height);
imagecopy($new, $bottom, 0, $top_height+1, 0, 0, $bottom_width, $bottom_height);

// save to file
imagepng($new, 'merged_image.png');
```

.. but the merged image doesn't have both images. PHP reports this:

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): '/Users/myusername/Work/www/projectname/staticimage.jpg' is not a valid PNG file in /Users/myusername/Work/www/projectname/imageWatermark.php on line 60

Warning: imagecopy() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/myusername/Work/www/projectname/imageWatermark.php on line 74
```

Comment: It works fine for me. can see Both images.

Comment: same here. Images broken? Files don't exist?

Comment: BTW, you can use `$new_width = max($top_width, $bottom_width)`.

Comment: yes. I checked different images then I saw images broken.

Comment: The paths are correct, however, they are filesystem paths (/user/myname/...) could that be the problem?

Comment: No, that's what they should be. Maybe you should use `imagecopyresized` to scale the bottom image when you copy it?

Comment: Yep, same here; success.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Ah yes, php reported `warnings`

Comment: `staticimage.jpg'` that needs to be `.png` as per the warning. Since you're using `imagecreatefrompng()` - You would need to use `imagecreatefromjpeg()`

Comment: Oh well, that works, so looks like both had to be PNGs. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can either delete the question since it's been solved in comments, or I can submit an answer. The choice is yours. Either way is ok. I'm just glad it got resolved.

Comment: Yes please, submit an answer, might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: It has been done @3zzy *cheers*

Comment: @3zzy I've made a slight edit to my answer, where you can use both `imagecreatefrompng()` and `imagecreatefromjpeg()` together, which worked for me while testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said/solved in comments, and the warnings that showed after your using error reporting:

Both files need to be `.png` where you are using a `.jpg`.

> imagecreatefrompng(): '/Users/myusername/Work/www/projectname/staticimage.jpg'

You can't intermix both different file/image formats, not when using `imagecreatefrompng()` with a `.jpg` file that is.

*Sidenote:* Simply renaming a `.jpg` to `.png` won't work as this will end up being a corrupt file (*for starters*) and will still thrown a warning, just as a quick FYI. It must be an actual PNG image format.

*However,* you could do: (should you wish to use both file formats from different files), would require using two different functions with their respected image formats.

```
$top_file = 'image1.png';
$bottom_file = 'image2.jpg';

$top = imagecreatefrompng($top_file);
$bottom = imagecreatefromjpeg($bottom_file);
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.